# sahi screenshot images to desire folder

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, sahi

i a automating my web , there are multiple requirements but one that make me sick is that i want to take snapshot of the web page and then save it into my desire location . It is taking snapshot but not saving in my desire location it saves in it default location . Can anyone help me out , how this can be cater.

below is my sample code

_takeScreenShot("D:\SAHI\result\capture.jpg", true, {format:'jpg', resizePercentage:75});

Please this is one of my deliverables .

Comment: one more thing , there is a variable in my location string. like
_writeToFile("C;/SAHI/data/"+$var+"/result.html);
this is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes in your string:

"D:\SAHI\result\capture.jpg"

Needs to be

"D:\\SAHI\\result\\capture.jpg"

Comment: use that bro . nothing happened .

Comment: This worked for me:

_takeScreenShot("D:\\SAHI\\result\\capture.jpg", true, {format:'jpg', resizePercentage:75});


Did you add slashes after the "D:"?  Your original path was missing them.  If that didn't work it may be that you don't have permission to write to that directory, try saving it to your Documents folder just to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: my writetofile in working fine on that particular folder thats mean i can write into that folder but screenshot wasn't working. i tried all the possible pattern of slashes but it didn't did the trick